# Xamarin Forms: How to remove the SelectedItem's backgroundcolor of CollectionView

Tags: xamarin, collectionview

The ItemSource of my CollectionView is a list of ToggleButtons, each ToggleButton item should be checked for the first time clicking, and be set to unchecked for the second time clicking. Then the question is comming.
Q1: There will be no any response for the second time's clicking if the clicked item is just the currently selected item.
For Q1, my temporary solution is like this , i added a TabGesture on the Grid of the DataTemplate, and some behind code to deal with the SelectItem switching. The partial xaml code is as following,

```
<CollectionView x:Name="_funBtnsContainer" ItemsSource="{Binding ParasViewModel.ClickParameters}" ItemsLayout="HorizontalList" SelectedItem="{Binding ParasViewModel.SelectedParamter , Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single" >
            <CollectionView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                        <VisualStateGroupList>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" 
                                                Value="Black" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" 
                                                Value="Black" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateGroupList>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </CollectionView.Resources>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <customCtrl:ToggleButtonWOGes Margin="0,0,5,0" WidthRequest="60"
                                Text="{Binding CaptionExt}" NormalStateImage="ic_pan2_common_normal" CheckedImage="ic_pan2_common_selected" DisableStateImage="ic_pan2_common_disabled"
                                IsEnable="{Binding IsEnable}"
                                Checked="{Binding IsChecked}">

                        </customCtrl:ToggleButtonWOGes>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

and the code behind ParaItem_Tapped function is like this,

```
var grid = (Grid)sender;
            ObjectParameterValueViewModel opvv = (ObjectParameterValueViewModel)grid.BindingContext;
            if(opvv == _funBtnsContainer.SelectedItem)
            {
                _funBtnsContainer.SelectedItem = null;
            }else
            {
                _funBtnsContainer.SelectedItem = opvv;
            }
```

Basically it seems it can solve the problem. But another problem occurred which is there will always be a gray background flashing when the SelectedItem is set to null.
I hope to remove this gray background. My temp solution will be perfect if the gray background can be removed. Does anyone know how to remove the gray background color?

Answer (score 0):

Since you had used MVVM , it would be better to handle the logic in ViewModel .

In your case , you could implement it by set the backgroundColor of the DataTemplate .

#### in xaml

Binding the **BackgroundColor** to Model and you don't need to set the Resources any more .

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}">
   //...    
</Grid>
```

#### in Model

Add a propertry `BackgroundColor`

```
public class MyModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        Color bgColor;
        public Color BackgroundColor
        {
            get
            {
                return bgColor;
            }
            set
            {
                if(bgColor!=value)
                {
                    bgColor = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("BackgroundColor");
                }
            }
        }

        //... other properties

    }
```

#### in ViewModel

```
    MyModel selectedParamter;
        public MyModel SelectedParamter
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedParamter;
            }
            set
            {
                if(selectedParamter != value)
                {
                    selectedParamter = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedParamter");



                    foreach(MyModel model in ClickParameters)
                    {
                        if(model!= SelectedParamter)
                        {
                            model.BackgroungColor = Color.Gray; // set background color for other item
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            model.BackgroungColor = Color.Red; // set background color for selected item
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: em... I just want to remove the background color. The actual problem is when the SelectedItem is set to null, there will be a gray color background appeared and disappeared quickly. I don't want any color appeared at that time, i just need transparent color when the SelectedItem is set null.

Comment: Could you provide a screen shot to show the effect that you want achieve ?